# onprogressupdate calling publishprogress

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am a beginner, I was searching for android AsyncTask on google. I search a lot, but I found this picture and make me confuse.

[image link from abhiandroid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E5QZ.png)

So I have one doubt.

1. is onProgressUpdate() method calling back doInbackground() method ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wherever required. Also please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think they are wrong. publishProgress() is calling onProgressUpdate() method on doInBackground().

onProgressUpdate() does not call doInBackground() back.

here is the documentation link

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)